# How to add exception to WindowOpened event?

Tags: java

I have a function like this:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {      

    Connection conn = null; // connection object
    Statement stmt = null; // statement object
    ResultSet rs = null; // result set object
    DatabaseMetaData metadata = null;

    try {
        conn = getConnection(); // without Connection, cannot do much
        metadata = conn.getMetaData();
        rs = metadata.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
        if (checkDefaultTables(rs)) {
            lStatus.setText("Message: Please insert 2 tables recommend");
        }

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ce) {
        // if the driver class not found, then we will be here
        System.out.println(ce.getMessage());
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        // something went wrong, we are handling the exception here
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.rollback();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        System.out.println("--- SQLException Caught ---");
        // iterate and get all of the errors as much as possible
        while (e != null) {
            System.out.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("ErrorCode: " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("---");
            e = e.getNextException();
        }
    } finally {
        // close the db resources
        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I get a error is exception required in lines `conn = getConnection()`, `conn.rollback()`, and `conn.setAutoCommit(true)`. I try to add  `throws SQLException, Exception` after `private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)` but I can't edit this line.

How do I add exceptions for this situation?

P/S: I'm using NetBean IDE and I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you edit the signature?

Is it coming from a superclass? Do you have access to it? You should consult the author of the API to include your needs there. There is no option to extend the exception list of method in a subclass (though can be omitted though).

OTOH, you can throw unmanaged exceptions (subclasses of *RuntimeException*). They neither have to be declared nor handled (like *NumberFormatException*, *IndexOutOfBoundsException*).

Take a look on the [Exceptions chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) of the official Java Tutorial to clarify the base concepts of the language.